# Attempting to find max and min values of an array through a function, where the array values are by user input

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to create a program where the user is asked for 10 numbers, the numbers are all stored in an array list, and then the array list is put through a function, the function is going to return the max and min values.

So far I only have code for a max value but I can't get the function to work at all, I've been using this link to learn about passing arrays to functions:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

And I think I'm following their syntax correctly but I'm getting errors about the array not being declared in the function parameter, and how my function (minmax) simply cannot be used as a function and I'm beyond confused right now!

Apologies if the answer is obvious, I'm still new to C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;


int minmax(array[]);

int main()
{

int numbers[10];
int input;

cout << "Please enter ten numbers" << endl;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

    cin >> input;
    numbers[i] = input;

    mm = minmax(numbers);

}

}

void minmax(array[]){


int max = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++);
{
    if (list[i] > highNum)
        max = array[i];
        cout << array[i];
}
cout << max;

}
```

Comment: Where is the data type of the array in the function definition?

Comment: `int minmax(array[]);` and then `void minmax(array[]){ ...` why void. and without return you try `mm = minmax(numbers);`

Comment: Instead of `array[]`  say `int array[]` or, better, `int const array[]`.

Comment: I would suggest switching from `int array[]` to `std::vector<int>`.  If you can use the standard containers do so.  They have so many things to make life easier.  In this case they include methods to find the max and min.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is not a homework assignment (which would probably require you to actually roll your own "Min/max" function), this code would suffice:

```
std::vector<int> values(10);
cout << "Please enter ten numbers" << endl;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    cin >> values[i];
}

int min_value = *std::min_element(values.begin(), values.end());
int max_value = *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Or if you need min/max values to be calculated with a single function invocation, you can rewrite those last two lines like this:

```
auto minmax = std::minmax_element(values.begin(), values.end());
int min_value = *(minmax.first);
int max_value = *(minmax.second);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int minmax(int* array, int size);

int main()
{
    int numbers[10];
    int input, mm;

    cout << "Please enter ten numbers" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cin >> input;
        numbers[i] = input;
    }

    mm = minmax(numbers, 10);

}

int minmax(int array, int size){
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++);
    {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
            cout << array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Should work, but you should (re)read the C/C++ basics.

Another solution is to use `<vector>` and `<algorithm>` from std C++ lib.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is not a homework assignment, here are some suggestions for your approach. (otherwise, @Xirema's answer is better approach)
3 things to start:
1) `mm` is not defined in your main.
2)  the statement: `mm = minmax(numbers);` should be moved out of the for loop.
3)  Also, this statement: `mm = minmax(numbers);` Suggests you need to change the function prototype of `minmax` in a couple of ways.  See below.

Replace your minmax function (see comments in code for explanation)

```
int minmax(int array[], int size)//need types for arguments 
                                 //(int) and prototype needs 
                                 //to return a value (void -> int)
{

    int max = INT_MIN;//<limits.h> initialize to negative
                      // (-2147483647 - 1) for 32 bits
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > max)
        {                    //added braces to be explict
             max = array[i]; // `list` should be `array`
                             //highNum is not needed, use max.
             cout << array[i];//Note, without curly braces, this 
                             //statement would not be executed
        }
    }
    cout << max;
    return max;  //requires a return value
}
```

Note, This preserves the result of what your original code example would have returned, maximum only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct some mistakes:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;


int minmax(/*no type specified, should be int*/array[]);

int main()
{

    int numbers[10];
    int input;
    /*mm is not declared, but is used later, declare it*/

    cout << "Please enter ten numbers" << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        cin >> input;
        numbers[i] = input;
        /*if minmax is void, then it cannot be assineg*/
        mm = minmax(numbers);

    }

}

/*minmax returns int in declaration, here returns void*/ void minmax(/*no type specified*/array[]){


    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < /*size was not declared, declare it*/ size ; i++);
    {
        if (/*list is undeclared, (did you mean array?)*/list[i] > /*highNum not declared, did you mean max?*/highNum)
            max = array[i];
        cout << array[i];
    }
    cout << max;

}
```

Comment: Hi, I really like the way you did this because it's a lot easier to learn this way. I've followed your instructions as to where my errors are and declaration seems to be my biggest issue. However it doesn't allow me to declare the function as int both times, I also cannot declare the array as type int twice, so I only did it for the declaration at the top. But for the actual function I cannot use void or int, what should I be using?

Comment: @Dante. If you followed instructions, then there aren't many thing to change. Let's assume that minmax returns `int` , and type of array in argument is also `int`. Let's also add one more argument to the function, the size (the one that was undeclared), so it will return max from only numbers you have already inputed. The changes: declaration: `int minmax( int array[], int size);`, mm assignment: `mm = minmax(numbers, i+1);`, Function under main should have exact return type and arguments. Also note important thing - there is `;` after you loop in function. Remove it, or it will do nothing.